# How to replace "(" with "\(" in the regexp, Emacs/elisp flavor?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Question as title.

More specifically, I'm rather tired of having to type `\(`, etc. every time I want a parenthesis in Emacs's (interactive) regexp functions (not to mention the `\\(` in code). So I wrote something like

```
(defadvice query-replace-regexp (before my-query-replace-regexp activate)
   (ad-set-arg 0 (replace-regexp-in-string "(" "\\\\(" (ad-get-arg 0)))
   (ad-set-arg 0 (replace-regexp-in-string ")" "\\\\)" (ad-get-arg 0)))))
```

in hope that I can conveniently forget about emacs's idiosyncrasy in regexp during "interaction mode". Except I cannot get the regexp right...

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "(" "\\\\(" "(abc")
```

gives `\\(abc` instead of the wanted `\(abc`. Other variations on the number of slashes just gives errors. Thoughts?

Since I started questioning, might as well ask another one: since lisp code is not supposed to use interactive functions, advicing `query-replace-regexp` should be okay, am I correct?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  A literal `(` matches itself.  `\\(` starts a capture when you aren't in a double-quoted string. `\\\(` starts a capture when you are in a double-quoted string.  Not all that confusing, just different from, say, perl which parses regexps differently from double-quoted strings.  Use `rx` if this really bothers you.

Also, lisp code can call interactive functions.  It just shouldn't call interactive functions that messes with the mark or kill ring.

Comment: @jrockway: I use grouped expression much more than trying to match real parenthesis, and having to type \\(something\\) all the time is tiring. The emacs flavor of regexp is the only one I know that requires quoting the parenthesis - though not surprisingly given the amount of parenthesis in lisp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The replacement you has works well for me.

Take the text:

```
hi there mom
hi son!
```

and try query-replace-regexp with your advice:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp (hi).*(mom) RET \1 \2! RET
```

yields

```
hi mom!
hi son!
```

I didn't have to put a backslash in front of the parentheses to get them to group.  That said, this disables being able to match actual parentheses...

The reason the `replace-regexp-in-string` yields `\\(abc`, is that as a *string*, that is equivalent to an interactively typed `\(abc`.  In a string `\` is used to denote that the following character is special, e.g. `"\t"` is a string with a tab.  So, in order to specify just a backslash, you need to use a backslash in front of it `"\\"` is a string containing a backslash.

Regarding advising interactive functions, lisp code can call interactive functions all it wants.  A prime example is `find-file` - which is called all over the place.  To make your advice a little safer, you can wrap the body with a check for `interactive-p` to avoid mussing with internal calls:

```
(defadvice query-replace-regexp (before my-query-replace-regexp activate)
  (when (interactive-p)
    (ad-set-arg 0 (replace-regexp-in-string "(" "\\\\(" (ad-get-arg 0)))
    (ad-set-arg 0 (replace-regexp-in-string ")" "\\\\)" (ad-get-arg 0)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the (interactive-p) part. I think I was confused by the scratch buffer and forgot that it returns the properly escaped string.